# How do I place element at bottom of webpage in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I've been trying to fix the positioning of my last element to sit at the bottom of my webpage, but it doesn't always fit correctly. In desktop view or when first loading mobile view, it seems fine, but it doesnt adjust as you scroll. See images below. Am I structuring my elements incorrectly?

```
    <div class="text-white text-center mx-auto my-2 w-2/3">
    <p>
      Welcome to "GlamourLocks," where your hair's beauty and style take center
      stage. Nestled in the heart of the city, our chic and contemporary hair
      salon is a sanctuary for those seeking the ultimate in hair care and
      transformation. At GlamourLocks, we understand that your hair is an
      expression of your unique personality, and our team of experienced
      stylists is dedicated to helping you unleash your inner beauty. Whether
      you're looking for a fresh haircut, a bold new color, or a special
      hairstyle for that special occasion, we've got you covered. Our salon is
      not just a place for hair services; it's a space where you can relax,
      rejuvenate, and leave feeling more confident and glamorous than ever
      before. Discover the magic of GlamourLocks, where every strand of hair is
      a work of art, and every client is a VIP.
    </p>
    </div>
    
      <div class="space-y-1 w-full absolute bottom-0">
        <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 1px"></div>
        <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 2px"></div>
        <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 3px"></div>
        <div class="flex relative bg-white w-full h-24 items-center justify-center">
          <img src="../img/logo.png" class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 h-20 object-contain"></img>
          <p class="absolute left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 bottom-0 text-xs">Designed by Julian Ordaz</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image: Click here: image is fine]
[image: Click here: issue when scrolling]

I've been expecting the element to always sit at the bottom, even as I scroll. Currently, it seems like it loads and sits at the bottom relative to the screen, not the entire page.

Comment: Sounds like you want fixed positioning rather than absolute. Never used Tailwind before, but I assume the `absolute` class on this div `<div class="space-y-1 w-full absolute bottom-0">` should be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider applying `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute` by replacing the `absolute` class with `fixed`. This will mean the element will be  positioned relative to the viewport and such that scrolling will not affect its position relative to the viewport:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="text-white text-center mx-auto my-2 w-2/3">
  <p>
    Welcome to "GlamourLocks," where your hair's beauty and style take center stage. Nestled in the heart of the city, our chic and contemporary hair salon is a sanctuary for those seeking the ultimate in hair care and transformation. At GlamourLocks, we
    understand that your hair is an expression of your unique personality, and our team of experienced stylists is dedicated to helping you unleash your inner beauty. Whether you're looking for a fresh haircut, a bold new color, or a special hairstyle
    for that special occasion, we've got you covered. Our salon is not just a place for hair services; it's a space where you can relax, rejuvenate, and leave feeling more confident and glamorous than ever before. Discover the magic of GlamourLocks, where
    every strand of hair is a work of art, and every client is a VIP.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="space-y-1 w-full fixed bottom-0">
  <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 1px"></div>
  <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 2px"></div>
  <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 3px"></div>
  <div class="flex relative bg-white w-full h-24 items-center justify-center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/80" class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 h-20 object-contain"></img>
    <p class="absolute left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 bottom-0 text-xs">Designed by Julian Ordaz</p>
  </div>
</div>
```